# How can this function which has undefined argument be able to run?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/44795246/3416774, the essence of the code is:

```js
network.on("afterDrawing", function (ctx) {
    var dataURL = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
});
```

How can it run? `ctx` isn't defined anywhere. In the [Vis.js' documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#Events), the `afterDrawing` event has this description:

| Name | Properties | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| afterDrawing | canvas context | Fired after drawing on the canvas has been completed. Can be used to draw on top of the network. |

Comment: the `afterDrawing` event provides the `ctx` to the passed callback. see the [docs](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#Events)

Comment: this is a concept called `callback functions`, once `.on` is done doing it's thing, it will return a value `ctx` which you can use in your code.

Comment: "isn't defined anywhere". Well, it is defined as parameter of the `function`.

Comment: And listed as a 'property' of the `afterDrawing` event in the docs (though this is confusing language).

Comment: @pilchard ah, `ctx` is short for `canvas context`. So when the method `on()` completes, it will return the canvas context so the `function` can pick up?

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx` is short for canvas context. So when the method `on()` completes, it will return the canvas context so the function can pick up. This is a concept called callback functions.